# Dynamic Pivot without XML Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have the following table:

`Product        Price($)        Qty       SellingDate
Book           10              10        1/10/2018
Book           15              20        1/10/2018
Pens           1               100       1/10.2018
Pens           2               50        1/10/2018
Misc           150             250       1/10/2018`

I have sales price and qty of different products. I would like to perform a pivot to get output in the following format:

`Book           Pens         Misc
(Price*Qty)   (Price*Qty)  (Price*Qty)`

I can have more or less number/type of products sold in a day. I am maintaining the products in a product master. Hence I would like to implement a dynamic pivot.

I tried the pivot query as below:

```
select * from 
(select product, (price*qty ) amnt
 from Sales_data where sellingdate = '1/10/2018')
PIVOT (MIN(amnt) FOR product IN (select distinct product from product_master);
```

When I execute the above query I get the "missing expression" error.

From what I have read, I have understood that dynamic pivot can be performed using XML and the output can then be extracted from the xml output.

However, to extract the result in a readable format, I would still need to know the number of returned columns.

Is there any way to implement dynamic pivot without having to generate XML output?

Comment: What client is going to read this report?